# Segmentation Fault Reading in Large Data Array Stored in CSV

Tags: c, csv, fgets

I'm completing a CUDA programming homework problem and struggling with reading the large data set in. I'm running remotely via SSH on a machine through my university.

I'm dealing with three columns of data and 2^25 rows in a CSV file. Each time I run my code I get a segmentation fault reading in the data around the 900th iteration of my while loop that is scanning the CSV.

I've done extensive searching on stack overflow and tried several different methods for reading the data in.

```
static double inputs[2^25]; 
static double outputs[2^25]; 
static double txval[2^25]; 

FILE *input = fopen("coins.csv", "r");
int j = -99; 
char buffer[1024];
char *field; 
unsigned long k = 0; 

if(input == NULL){
    printf("Unable to open file\n"); 
    return 1; 
}

while(fgets(buffer, 1024, input) && k < 2^25){

    // skip the first row with column titles 
    if(j == -99){
        j = 0; 
    }

    else{
    field = strtok(buffer, ","); 
    inputs[k] = atof(field); 

    field = strtok(NULL, ","); 
    outputs[k] = atof(field); 

    field = strtok(NULL, ","); 
    txval[k] = atof(field); 

    k = k + 1; 


    }
}
fclose(input);
```

Expected results are that the whole file would read in since the buffer is overwritten each time the while loop runs.

The actual results are that a segmentation fault occurs on the 900th or so iteration of the while loop every time.

Comment: Where and how have you defined/allocated the three arrays/pointers `inputs`, `outputs` and `txval`?

Comment: Apologies, I should have added that to my code. All three are defined a few lines above the code here and are defined as static double arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`2^25` is not "2 to the power 25". It is 2 XOR 25.

I suggest you use the value `33554432`.

Edit: (thanks @bruno)

`33554432` is easier to read as `1 << 25`.

Comment: thanks bruno and weather vane! turns out removing my accidental xor fixed my seg fault.

Comment: Try to allocate anything "substantial" on the heap using `malloc()` or `calloc()`. Also strive to avoid using global variables when there's better alternatives.

Comment: @TaylorPeters note the effect of operator precedence on `k < 2 ^ 25` which is evaluated as `(k < 2) ^ 25`. When `k < 2` it evaluates to `1 ^ 25` which is `24` and so the expression is `true`. When `k >= 2` it evaluates to `0 ^ 25` which is `25` and so the expression is again `true`, and is useless as a loop control. Beware of the lower precedence of bitwise operators to relational operators: you always need parentheses. The typical error occurs with, say `if(x & 3 == 0)` which should be `if((x & 3) == 0)`.